# Что такое вебхук – webhook? И как его подключить?

Tags: php, mysql, webhook

Я некоторое время реально не мог понять, что такое вебхук))
Оказалась это совершенно простая технология, поэтому особо никто и не пишет об этом. Сейчас опишу как это работает в связке с моей базой данных на PHP Mysql и в данном случае сайтом на тильде.
Думаю, это применимо и к другим конструкторам. Сам я не люблю конструкторы от слова СОВСЕМ, из за ограничений))), но в силу обстоятельств на моей работе приходится работать с конструкторами.
Вопрос задан не только, чтобы я сам дал на него ответ, но и может есть более интересные решения?

Answer (score 2):

На сервере два файла: **connect.php** и **webhook.php**

**connect.php**

в файле коннект прописываем подключение к базе данных.

```html
<?php
      
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');



      $server = "localhost"; /* имя хоста (уточняется у провайдера), если работаем на локальном сервере, то указываем localhost */
      $username = "usernameBD"; /* Имя пользователя БД */
      $password = "passwordBD"; /* Пароль пользователя, если у пользователя нет пароля то, оставляем пустым */
      $database = "nameBD"; /* Имя базы данных, которую создали */

      // Подключение к базе данный через MySQLi
      $mysqli = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

   


      //Для удобства, добавим здесь переменную, которая будет содержать название нашего сайта
      $address_site = "https:// example.com ";
  ?>
```

**webhook.php** Позже нам его нужно будет поменять, чтоб он отсылал данные в базу данных.

Ваш сайт с файлом: https://example.com/webhook.php (за место этого домена «example.com» должен быть ваш домен)
Эта ссылка и есть вебхук, берем эту ссылку и вставляем на сайте от куда отсылаются данные из формы.
Сначала вставляем этот тестовый код чтоб получить сообщение об успешном тесте (за место моей почты «anton.strobe@gmail.com» ставим свою)

```html
<?php  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$headers = "From: from@webhookservesite.ru";
$message = print_r($_POST,true);
@mail('anton.strobe@gmail.com', 'Tilda TEST', $message, $headers);
echo "ok";

?>
```

**webhook.php** Измененный вебхук.

В этом скрипте происходит два действия:

**1)**
Отправка массива данных сообщением на почту.

**2)**
Добавление данных в базу данных.

```html
<?php  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$headers = "From: from@webhookservesite.ru";
$message = print_r($_POST,true);
@mail('anton.strobe@gmail.com', 'Tilda TEST', $message, $headers);
echo "ok";

    require_once("connect.php");

$result_query_insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (full_name, login, email, password, avatar) VALUES ('".$_POST['full_name']."', '".$_POST['login']."', '".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['password']."', '".$_POST['avatar']."')");
        $result_query_insert->close();
        $mysqli->close();
?>
```

**Создание базы данных одним действием!**

Мы просто вбиваем в панели пхп-май-админ, в разделе SQL, вот эту команду, и нам не нужно вручную вписывать все поля, и создавать users.sql:

```html
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(355) DEFAULT NULL,
  `login` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```